# I don't know what's wrong with one of my variable.[Exception in thread "main" java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = 'm']

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LABEX03
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    { 
            System.out.println("Name LE01");
            Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
            double m = 3;
            double n = 0;
            System.out.print("type 12 and Press enter");
            n = kbd.nextInt();
            double p = (double)m * (double)n;
            double q = 0;
            q = (double)Math.sqrt(p);
            System.out.printf("%m");
            System.out.printf("%n");
            System.out.printf("%p");
            System.out.printf("%q");
    }
}
```

Debug:

Name LE01
type 12 and Press enter12
Exception in thread "main" java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = 'm'
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.conversion(Formatter.java:2691)
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.(Formatter.java:2720)
    at java.util.Formatter.parse(Formatter.java:2560)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2501)
    at java.io.PrintStream.format(PrintStream.java:970)
    at java.io.PrintStream.printf(PrintStream.java:871)
    at LABEX03.main(LABEX03.java:16)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 6 seconds)

Comment: Why are you doing n = kbd.nextInt()? Shouldn't you do kbd.nextDouble()?

Answer (score 3):

You've misunderstood what is supposed to be in the format string with the `%` signs.  The variable names don't go in the format string, they are passed as separate parameters to `printf`.  The format specifier indicates the type of the variable passed in, e.g. `%d` for integers, `%f` for floating-point numbers, and `%s` for string text.

Try e.g.:

```
System.out.printf("%f", m);
```

For further reference, see the [`Formatter` javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html), which gives more detail about how to format your strings and pass in variables.

Answer (score 0):

Your format statements aren't correct.

```
// Should print "q=2.0"
double q = Math.sqrt(4.0);
System.out.printf ("q=%g", q);
```

Here's the Javadoc:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be confused about the number and order of parameters for [`printf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29). I'm fairly certain you wanted something like,

```
System.out.printf("m = %f%n", m);
System.out.printf("n = %f%n", n);
System.out.printf("p = %f%n", p);
System.out.printf("q = %f%n", q);
```

When I run your code (with the above change) and input 12 I get

```
m = 3.000000
n = 12.000000
p = 36.000000
q = 6.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.printf("m = %f", m);
System.out.printf("n = %f", n);
System.out.printf("p = %f", p);
System.out.printf("q = %f", q);
```

I was able to change the (Int) into (Doubles) and change ("%m") into ("m = %f", m).
It worked well. Thanks everyone for the helpful tips